# Can I make gallery apps of famous celebrity like Justin and michel Jackson?

Tags: copyright, software

Not sure this is the right place to ask this question here or not? I asked this in stackoverflow/tags/android and they told me to ask here. As I am from developing county, here no one cares about using copyright material. I searched on play store like Justin gallery, Mj gallery but apps are not found. So, I think of creating the one of MJ. Do I have rights? I will also put ads on it, It means that I am taking credit from it. Please don't down vote for this question because I have already said that I am from developing country where no one cares about copyright. So, I don't know how are the laws of developed countries? For the images I will use googleImages. Thank You!! Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never heard of Justin Jackson and Michel Jackson.

Comment: Where's the Justin Jackson? hahaa :D funny gnasher, Micheal was the king of pop

Comment: Never heard of Michel Jackson, nor of Micheal Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two rights you could be violating here:

1. Personality rights of the depicted person
2. Copyright of the photographer

The first is the right of the person in the image. Laws on this vary widely around the world. In some countries, people can forbid the distribution of images which depict them under some circumstances. However, celebrities and other "people of public interest" usually have fewer rights than private people.

The second is the right of the photographer who took the picture. Thanks to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), this situation is far more homogeneous around the world: In most places around the world, a photograph is considered an artistic work by the photographer, regardless of what is depicted in the photo. That means the photographer has an exclusive copyright to their work and can usually take legal actions against anyone who uses their work without permission.